# usleep() function does not allow a loop to continue

Tags: c++, sleep

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i=0;
        while(i<10)
        {
                printf("%d", i);
                usleep(10000); // or sleep(1)
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I want the program to last 10 secs, i.e. print 1 - wait 1 sec - print 2 - wait 1 sec and so on until the end. But it doesn't do that - it just  waits for all the time (10 secs) and then prints the whole array of numbers together without any time delays between them, it just prints 0123456789 at once. 
EDIT: I tried with sleep() instead of usleep but it's the same 
How to fix it ? And why it's like that ?

Comment: also, if you want the program to last 10 seconds then you shouldn't just add multiple sleeps and add them because wach loop requires time to execute the printf and overhead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your output buffer is not being flushed. By default, output is written when a new line appears in the stream. Change your `printf` to this:

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

or try this:

```
printf("%d", i);
fflush(stdout);
```

Also, if you want to remove the line-buffering behaviour, you can use [`setvbuf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) and the `_IONBUF` mode.

Answer (score 5):

Aside - To pass 1 sec to `usleep`, call `usleep(1000000)`

Answer (score 3):

call `fflush(stdout)` after each printf to flush the buffered output